# p value adjust multiple populations

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

quite a simple question really. I am performing an exploratory analysis of 8 outcome measures, in 4 populations, with six blood tests. Therefore in this stage there are 8x4x6 comparisons performed!

Now each of the populations are different and exclusive. Each of the outcome measures has different populations owing to NA in some of the measures.

As I said this is exploratory, so hypothesis building.

I am wanting to perform some p value adjustment owing to the sheer amount of comparisons. My thinking is either:

1. No p value correction - accept this as a limitation
2. p value correct inclusive to each outcome measure AND population (so 6 comparison tests)
3. p value correct per outcome measure (24 tests). However the comparisons are not performed between the same popualtions.

Many thanks

Comment: If this is exploratory, why bother with p-values at all? What is your goal?

Comment: The goal is to provide descriptive analysis of a variety of blood tests in relation to clinical outcome. P values are being used to see where, and what direction there are significant associations before narrowing the scope.

Comment: See David's answer. He is totally right ! A regression model with between-within sample effect should do the job, depending on the data distribution for your outcome. If you need some guidance, provide some reproductible code and data, it will our pleasure to give you model and interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you do not need to correct for tests across independent samples. So you could correct for 8x6 tests within each population. Though, if the variables are the same, why not combine across populations first, and then test for between-population differences? This would give you better power to see correlations between the blood tests and outcomes. Now, the question of whether to correct or not comes down to what you are trying to learn. If you are still in a hypothesis-building phase, it would probably be more useful to largely ignore the p-values, and to instead focus on the effect sizes.